# YouTube API App remove youtube icon from a

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I have an android application for Android, using the youtube api for android, but I have this watching the video:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRCqN.png

When you tap on the wheel, the video title with those 2 icons, HQ and youtube shows, if I tap on youtube, I go to the youtube app, but I don't want that!

Looked in the code but im a bit newbie, any ideas how to remove it?

Thanks!